Integrating CMake,Visual Studio and QTest
I am trying to integrate CMake, Visual Studio and QTest.
I have tried the many suggestions, this is my latest, which upon building produces the error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    

Suppression State
Error   MSB3073 The command "setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\ctest.exe" --force-new-ctest-process -C Debug
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 8. RUN_TESTS   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  155 

This is my cmakeLists.txt
project(mytest LANGUAGES CXX)
find_package(Qt5Test REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
enable_testing(true)
add_executable(mytest tst_mytest.cpp)
add_test(NAME mytest COMMAND mytest)
target_link_libraries(mytest PRIVATE Qt5::Test)

This is the code
#include <QtTest>

class MyTest : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void testMyFunction();
};

void MyTest::testMyFunction() {
    // Your test code here
    QVERIFY(true);
}

QTEST_MAIN(MyTest)

#include "mytest.moc"

I cannot see what I am doing incorrectly

You should find the more detailed information about the problem. The output in your question post just tells that "something was wrong".
